# DotNet Command line errors

Tags: .net, .net-core, command-line-interface

I am trying the "getting started" tutorial for DotNet command line at: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-with-xplat-cli

The entire tutorial is to fire up a command prompt - I used admin mode - and run the following two DotNet commands:

1. $ dotnet new console
2. $ dotnet run

The first one succeeded though it took several minutes.
The second failed after a very long time.

The log showed about 20 error messages that all looked similar to this:

> _7.9.0.5.cs(1081,43): error CS0229: Ambiguity between 'IWOA.DllName' and 'IWOA.D
>   llName' [C:\Windows\system32\system32.csproj]
>   wbem\Framework\root\citrix\VdaParameters\BrokerAgent_SN_a80ce61cfbf8b47a_Version

1. They all mention this dll: 'IWOA.DllName'
2. They all have citrix in the folder path.

I rarely post here since I can usually find answers to my question with some online digging but this one stumps me. I was unable to find even the slightest reference on line to this problem.

So what in the world is going on here?

FYI: Visual studio version is 15.8.8 and as far as I can tell my whole environment is uo to date.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy moly!

You are probably missing some important context:

1. Don't use admin mode (or root!)
2. `dotnet` works on projects, which it assumes is the entire directory that it's operating in, recursively.

The expecation is that you will create a new folder, with no existing files, and then run `dotnet new console` and `dotnet run`.

What you seem to have done is to go to an existing (system) folder, and run dotnet run on that. That actually tries to scan all of `C:\Windows\system32\` and figure out how to build/run it. You can guess that this is not going to work because it's finding random code and dll's and tries to figure out how to build/run it.

So just use a new empty directory for creating new project.